# Numpy fast fill 3D matrix

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

Can the following code be accelerated using numpy functions

```
def fill3D(x,y,z,n):
    M = np.zeros((n,n,n))
    for i,j,k in zip(x,y,z):
        M[i,j,k] += 1
    return M
```

Here `x,y,z` are lists of indices for the corresponding dimensions of the matrix `M`

The index triplets `(i,j,k)` are non-unique. Some matrix entries will stay at `0`, some will be `1`, some will be larger than that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution could be to use `np.unique()` in order to count the number of repeated index and then assign the values:

```
import numpy as np

# Dummy index, with duplicate entries
x = np.array([1, 0, 0])
y = np.array([0, 1, 1])
z = np.array([2, 2, 2])

# Empty 3x3x3 matrix
M = np.zeros((3,3,3))

# Count and assign the new values:
ind,val = np.unique(np.vstack((x,y,z)),return_counts=True,axis=1)
M[ind[0],ind[1],ind[2]] = val
```